# Paypal button failed to process some user payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

We integrated Paypal button to support our starting business. We received several user feedbacks about not being able to complete payment. They reported that they can see the payment page after clicking the Buy Now button. However they tried pay through Paypal account, pay with credit card and pay with Paypal credit. None of them work. However, no one in our team has faced such problem when checking out. So we really don't have an idea about what's going on. Here is an example Paypal button code we use:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="business@myticket.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="env" value="www">
    <input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="演唱会">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="122">
    <input type="hidden" name="discount_rate_1" value="10">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="演唱会">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="122">
    <input type="hidden" name="discount_rate_2" value="10">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="$27.95">
    <!-- Fill full name in the first_name field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="Bruce Lee">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.myticket.com/payment/ipn">
    <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="state" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="country" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="lmIvjDuZVRsCWFPDdfFsrKiNVrnAbWeTZSINiDuszZEGKjeXfhqxyqRrn">
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="authorization">
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.myticket.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.myticket.com">
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/checkout-logo-large.png" alt="Check out with PayPal">
</form>
```

Is there any problem with this Paypal button? If not, what else could be causing the payment to fail?

Besides, is there a way we can get a message about these failures? Right now we are using IPN. However IPN doesn't seem to notify us about these payment failures.

BTW, myticket.com is a fake url in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Well first, when using Website Payments Standard buttons, you don't get much back as far as the declines.  Typically you are only going to get details of declines back when you are using API calls to process the payment.  As for the button itself, it looks fine to me.  Perhaps some of the issue is with the special characters for the item name which is leading to the failure.  You could try creating 2 of the same buttons/items but without the special characters and see if those same buyers run into the issue with the second button that they did with the first one.  You could also try using the "lc" variable in your button code to see if this helps.  You can see the description of what the "lc" variable does [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0709B).